# Write a class for a warehouse that hold radios

Tags: c#

“Write a class for a warehouse that hold radios,
televisions, and computers. Provide a constructor that starts a 
warehouse with no items. Include instance variables to store the
quantity of each item in the warehouse. Include methods to add to the 
stock of each item, and a method to display the contents of the warehouse.
Test in a Main method, creating two warehouses. Add items to each and 
display the final contents of each warehouse.”

```
using System;
public class warehouse
{
    int radios, televisions, computers;

    public warehouse()
    {
        radios = televisions = computers = 0;
    }

    public void addRadioStock()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the number of radios in stock.");
        string radiosInput = Console.ReadLine();
        Convert.ToInt16(radiosInput);
    }

    public void addTelevisionsStock()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the number of televisions in stock.");
        string televisionsInput = Console.ReadLine();
        Convert.ToInt16(televisionsInput);
    }

    public void addComputersStock()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the number of computers in stock.");
        string computersInput = Console.ReadLine();
        Convert.ToInt16(computersInput);
    }

    public void Display()
    {

        Console.WriteLine(" There are " + radios + " radios in stock.");
        Console.WriteLine(" There are " + televisions + " televisions in stock.");
        Console.WriteLine(" There are " + computers + " computers in stock.");
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        warehouse warehouse1 = new warehouse ();
        warehouse warehouse2 = new warehouse ();
        warehouse1.addRadioStock ();
        warehouse1.addTelevisionsStock ();
        warehouse1.addComputersStock ();
        warehouse2.addRadioStock ();
        warehouse2.addTelevisionsStock ();
        warehouse2.addComputersStock ();
        Console.WriteLine("Warehouse 1:");
        warehouse1.Display();
        Console.WriteLine("Warehouse 2:");
        warehouse2.Display();
    }
}
```

Unable to get the OUtput what wrong i'm doing

Comment: What do you mean you are "unable", what happens?

Comment: Please give your questions titles that don't sound like lazy requests and also read [mcve]

Answer (score 3):

Non of your functions, after converting to an `int` assigns the value to the class's member.

Change for example this:

```
public void addRadioStock()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the number of radios in stock.");
    string radiosInput = Console.ReadLine();
    Convert.ToInt16(radiosInput);
}
```

To this:

```
public void addRadioStock()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the number of radios in stock.");
    string radiosInput = Console.ReadLine();
    radios = Convert.ToInt16(radiosInput);
}
```

Also I recomment:

1. Look at the use of `int.TryParse`
2. Check [naming conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043(v=vs.100).aspx) in C#. And for a more overall look [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @Mohammed Kalimulla - Did this help you solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is here:

```
 Convert.ToInt16(computersInput);
```

Convert.ToInt16 parses an input and returns a number.  In each case you aren't assigning the returned number to anything.